# Read Time out when attempting to request a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape websites and I sometimes get this error and it is concerning as I randomly get this error but after i retry i do not get the error.

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.somewebsite.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)
```

My code looks like the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem
import requests

software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, OperatingSystem.LINUX.value]
user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names, operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=100)
pages_to_scrape = ['https://www.somewebsite1.com/page', 'https://www.somewebsite2.com/page242']

for page in pages_to_scrape:
  time.sleep(2)
  page = requests.get(page, headers={'User-Agent':user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()})
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
  # scrape info
```

As you can see from my code I even use Time to sleep my script for a couple of seconds before requesting another page. I also use a random user_agent. I am not sure if i can do anything else to make sure I never get the Read Time out error.

I also came across [this](https://github.com/swar/nba_api/issues/94) but it seems they are suggesting to add additional values to the headers but I am not sure if that is a generic solution because that may have to be specific from website to website. I also read on another [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717282/requests-httpconnectionpool-read-timeout-never-recovers) that we should base64 the request and retry. It went over my head as I have no idea how to do that and there was not a example provided by the person.

Any advice by those who have experience in scraping would highly be appreciated.

Comment: that's completely is not about the `User-Agent` or even the `time` which you have set within each `requests`, could you please confirm if you do that against different `sites` ? and if `yes`, can you share any of those sites ? also please let me know from where you run the script ? is it a `windows`? if yes, which `DNS` you are using

Comment: Are you sending multiple requests for the same site? Your code suggests that you are making just 1 request per site

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη the site is https://www.uniqlo.com/us/en/men/t-shirts

Comment: @Dinero well, I've verified your issue. Basically that site is using `AkamaiGHost` firewall. which will block your requests if it's without valid `User-Agent` and should be `stable`. you don't need to change it on each request. also you will need to use `requests.Session()` to persist the `session` and not causing `TCP` layer to drop the `packets`, I've been able to send 1k requests within the second and didn't get blocked. even i verified if the `bootstrap` will block the request if i parsed the `HTML` source but it didn't at all.

Comment: being informed that i launched all my tests using **Google DNS** which will never cause a `latency` on my threading which can lead the firewall to `drop` the requests and define it as `DDOS` attack. [Check](https://repl.it/repls/IdenticalCheeryBracket). One point to be noted as well. **DO NOT USE** `timeout=None` as that's will cause the request to wait forever for a `respons` where in the backend the firewall is automatically detecting any `TCP` listener which in pending state and automatically drop it and block the origin `IP` which is you. that's based on `time` configured :)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη that is awesome, can you post this as an answer with the code you used. So i can verify and accept your answer. Also can you tell me how you are able to tell the site is using AkamiGhost. I think it will help me with the learning process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, I've verified your issue. Basically that site is using `AkamaiGHost` firewall.

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -D - https://www.uniqlo.com/us/en/men/t-shirts
```

[image]

which will block your requests if it's without valid `User-Agent` and should be `stable`. you don't need to change it on each request. also you will need to use `requests.Session()` to persist the `session` and not causing `TCP` layer to drop the packets, I've been able to send 1k requests within the second and didn't get blocked. even i verified if the `bootstrap` will block the request if i parsed the HTML source but it didn't at all.

being informed that i launched all my tests using `Google DNS` which will never cause a latency on my threading which can lead the `firewall` to drop the requests and define it as `DDOS attack`. One point to be noted as well. `DO NOT USE timeout=None` as that's will cause the request to wait forever for a response where in the back-end the firewall is automatically detecting any `TCP listener` which in `pending state` and automatically drop it and block the `origin IP` which is you. that's based on time configured :) –

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Test(num):
    print(f"Thread# {num}")
    with requests.session() as req:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'}
        r = req.get(
            "https://www.uniqlo.com/us/en/men/t-shirts", headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return soup.title.text
        else:
            return f"Thread# {num} Failed"


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    futures = executor.map(Test, range(1, 31))
    for future in futures:
        print(future)
```

[Run It Online](https://repl.it/repls/IdenticalCheeryBracket)

Comment: requests.Session() - i did not see this in your code though?

Comment: @Dinero ops my mistake. i just inserted the first code. hold on

Comment: How do you figure out which user agent is "stable" i am just trying to understand your thinking process so in future if i want to scrape another site i know what to do

Comment: @Dinero well , I've running without `user-agent` and with `user-agent` and with `multiple user-agents` and i can confirm that point due to server response.

Answer (score 1):

ReadTimeout exceptions are commonly caused by the following

1. Making too many requests in a givin time period
2. Making too many requests at the same time
3. Using too much bandwidth, either on your end or theirs

It looks like your are making 1 request every 2 seconds. For some websites this is fine, others could be call this a denial-of-service attack. Google for example will slow down or block requests that occur to frequently.

Some sites will also limit the requests if you don't provide the right information in the header, or if they think your a bot.

To solve this try the following:

1. Increase the time between requests. For Google, 30-45 seconds works for me if I am not using an API
2. Decrease the number of concurrent requests.
3. Have a look at the network requests that occur when you visit the site in your browser, and try to mimic them.
4. Use a package like selenium to make your activity look less like a bot.

Comment: How do i look at the network request that occurs when i visit the site? any link or guidance on how to do that would help greatly.

Comment: @Dinero, in, e.g. Firefox use `Ctrl+Shift+I`, then go to Network tab and reload the page. You will see All requests made by visiting this webpage. You can switch to XHR sub-tab to see only requests made by JavaScript to some APIs and so on. All major browsers have the same developer tools, but shortcut maybe slightly different.

Comment: @Dinero In Chrome, use F12, then follow ololobus's instructions.